# Adding a class name to number input when input has value

Tags: javascript

I'm using pure JS to try to add a class to a number input when the input has a value. The first part of the JS (which adds the "checked" state) is working, but the portion that adds the class name ("selected") isn't being applied. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

This is a combined radio and number input, hence the extra input type.

```
function select_radio_item_other_button(text_obj, radio_but)
{
    if (document.getElementById)
    {
        el = document.getElementById(radio_but);
        if (el.checked)
            return;
        if (text_obj.value != '')
            el.checked = true;
        text_obj.className += " selected";
    }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="other">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_21" id="radio_21_22" checked="checked">
    <label for="radio_21_22" id="radio_21_22_amt">
    <input type="number" style="padding-left:0;" name="radio_21_22_amt" id="radio_21_22_amt" value="" min="0" max="50000000" step="1" onblur="javascript:select_radio_item_other_button(this, 'radio_21_22')">
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: why do we return when `el.checked` is truthy? if I comment out those lines, I see it adding the class name... perhaps the logic on checking the radio button (because of the label) needs re-doing...

Comment: The `id` must be unique within a page. You are using `id="radio_21_22_amt"` on both the label and the input, so your `document.getElementById()` will probably return the _label_ (first occurrence of the id) rather than the _input_. Other things: `el = document.get...` creates a _global_ variable; use _var_ `var el = document.get...`. Unless you're supporting _ancient_ browsers you don't need the `if (document.getElementById)` test these days. Also for modern browsers use `el.classList.add("selected")` rather than `+=` strings.

Comment: I created [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozxKRp) and it seems (to me) to work fine.  The only changes I made from your posted code are: 1) made sure id names are unique, 2) put in a 2nd radio button so I could test that, 3) don't pre-check any of the radio buttons, and 4) added `var` on `el` -- Still, I would do a _lot_ of this differently, partly depending on your target browser audience.  Inline `style=` and inline `onevent=` are generally bad practice; learn [`addEventListener`](http://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are a little off, perhaps something like this,

```
function select_radio_item_other_button(text_obj, radio_but) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        el = document.getElementById(radio_but);

        if (el.checked) {
            return;
        }

        if (text_obj.value != '') {
            el.checked = true;
            text_obj.className += " selected";
        }
    }
}
```

Also not sure what `if (document.getElementById)` is supposed to return but what were you trying to accomplish here? It evaluates to true but that seems like an unintended purpose!

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no `.valueOf()` function on an HTMLElement object; `el.value` is correct. The JS _String_ object has [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/valueOf) but `this` passed by the onblur handler is an element, not a String.

Comment: Ah yes I see! Misinterpreted what was being passed. Obviously if you're adding a class do it, it would be a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - I used a combination of your responses but this is working:

```
function select_radio_item_other_button(text_obj, radio_but)
{
   var el = document.getElementById(radio_but);

    if (text_obj.value != '') {
        el.checked = true;
        text_obj.className += " selected";
    }
}
```